# AES Encryption on OS X

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, encryption, aes

The codes below is working on iOS, however it doesn't work on OSX.
Because the framework of the Security is completely different between them.
So appreciate if anyone shares correct codes of the decrypt string for OSX.
Thanks

```
+ (NSData *)decryptData:(NSData *)data withKeyRef:(SecKeyRef) keyRef{
const uint8_t *srcbuf = (const uint8_t *)[data bytes];
size_t srclen = (size_t)data.length;

size_t block_size = SecKeyGetBlockSize(keyRef) * sizeof(uint8_t);
UInt8 *outbuf = malloc(block_size);
size_t src_block_size = block_size;

NSMutableData *ret = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
for(int idx=0; idx<srclen; idx+=src_block_size){
    //NSLog(@"%d/%d block_size: %d", idx, (int)srclen, (int)block_size);
    size_t data_len = srclen - idx;
    if(data_len > src_block_size){
        data_len = src_block_size;
    }

    size_t outlen = block_size;
    OSStatus status = noErr;

    status = SecKeyDecrypt(keyRef,
                           kSecPaddingNone,
                           srcbuf + idx,
                           data_len,
                           outbuf,
                           &outlen
                           );
    if (status != 0) {
        NSLog(@"SecKeyEncrypt fail. Error Code: %d", (int)status);
        ret = nil;
        break;
    }else{
        //the actual decrypted data is in the middle, locate it!
        int idxFirstZero = -1;
        int idxNextZero = (int)outlen;
        for ( int i = 0; i < outlen; i++ ) {
            if ( outbuf[i] == 0 ) {
                if ( idxFirstZero < 0 ) {
                    idxFirstZero = i;
                } else {
                    idxNextZero = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        [ret appendBytes:&outbuf[idxFirstZero+1] length:idxNextZero-idxFirstZero-1];
    }
}

free(outbuf);
CFRelease(keyRef);
return ret;
}
```

Comment: `Security.framework` on iOS and OSX are different how?

Comment: Basically the Security.framework for OS X is missing the SecKeyEncrypt.
Maybe I am wrong, but I cannot run the method `+ (NSData *)decryptData:(NSData *)data withKeyRef:(SecKeyRef) keyRef` on OS X which is true.